# Using another Subversion repository within a project

Tags: linux, tuleap

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a subversion repository , located in another server than the Tuleap server, within a Tuleap project.

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible. Some of the complication comes from running checks on the commits in the post-commit svn hooks. Checks include mandatory commit message and/ or commit messages with corss-references in them.